# Can tags effectively isolate the set of solution avenues to which I have access?

Tags: discussion, tags

Often, when browsing or searching SharePoint.SE, I come across questions that closely relate to a situation I'm experiencing, but that are nevertheless not helpful to me, either because they were framed in the specific context of an aspect of SharePoint administration to which I do not have access, or because they were generally framed, but have an accepted answer that utilizes such an approach, and thus, any answer that I could implement in my environment was never posted.
*(To be clear, I'm only referring to questions where I have reasonably high certainty that there also exists some solution using a tool that I do have at my disposal.)*

My specific situation:

- I'm the Site Collection Administrator for a small team within a large corporate organization, so I have access to (nearly) everything in the browser UI that an SCA can be expected to have available (though I do know that there are a few links that the server team have hidden from the Site Settings page e.g. due to compatibility concerns).
- The organization's general SharePoint guidelines are:

  - Use OOTB, no-code solutions whenever possible.
  - Do not create/use a solution that negatively impacts the performance of other sites.
  - If you have to use SharePoint Designer and/or write custom code, this is allowed, but is considered "Community Supported", subject to your colleagues' availability and willingness to help - otherwise, you're on your own.
  - Such customizations should be kept to a minimum, to avoid inflation of the training, skillset, and/or acclimation timeframe of a replacement, in the event that you get reassigned, or leave the organization.
  - InfoPath is specifically disallowed, due to some compatibility issue with a Managed Metadata column that is set as "required" on all content.
- The servers were recently upgraded to SP2013, but all sites are still running in "2010 mode" and the upgrade option is currently disabled by the server admins.
- I have access to SharePoint Designer (2013) and often use it for custom workflows (2010 workflow platform only until upgrade phase 2). For anything else, I avoid using SPD unless it's the only viable option, as per the aforementioned support guidelines.
- I can use Page Viewer and Content Editor web parts to add CSS or JavaScript to a page.
- Importing custom templates, web parts, etc. from the Internet is prohibited. Code snippets are ok, with conditions:

  - I'm responsible for supporting any code I use, so I must thoroughly understand it, and should be capable of explaining it to someone else.
  - I can't obtain and use code in such a way that might expose the organization to liability for a license violation. (Basically, I have to write the code myself, unless it's CC0 or CC-BY only, or is too trivial to constitue an "original work".)
- I do not have access to PowerShell or Central Administration.
- A lot of questions and answers refer to things like SCOM, and those are way over my head.

**Is there a tag, or set of 2-3 tags, that I can put on a question I ask that will help to ensure that I get answers I can implement**, without having to replicate a substantial portion of the above details in the question text every time? Simply using the OOTB tag would be too restrictive, but if I need 5 tags to do it, then I can no longer categorize my question by its content.

Similarly, **how should I set up tag filters to maximize the ratio of questions I could hope to answer, given the details above?**

Answer (score 4):

The thing about Tags is that they are here to give a more or less quick insight into what **areas** of SharePoint the question touches.

You are asking for a way to reduce the details in your questions, which is an anti-pattern, as we **need** this information to understand your skill level, your restrictions, your environment, and your organizational prohibitions.

Far too often we see questions where people want to know how to solve X.
There exist many ways to solve it, but we need to know all the things you've listed above to give you the best possible answer.

Tags don't tell us you're not allowed to use Full-Trust solutions, or that you don't have access to PowerShell or Central Administration - The details in your question should tells this.

Comment: What about the [tag:OOTB] tag?

Comment: @DanHenderson You could still have a solution involving "out of the box" features that would require you to have access to central administration - we would still not be able to tell if you were able to do that or not if you only tagged it with `ootb` - you would still need to provide more info in the question.

Comment: Ok. In that case, I'd like to distill that huge wall of text down to a much more concise version. Are there key terms or phrases that can succinctly replace any significant portions of it? If I have to say all this with each question I ask, I'd like to do so with as much brevity as can still preserve clarity. Also, can you answer the 2nd part of my question, about effective tag filter use when browsing open questions? I have plenty of expertise with the tools at my disposal, but so many of the questions on SP.SE involve those other aspects of SharePoint with which I lack sufficient experience.

Comment: @DanHenderson Probably best to answer something like that as another question -- I think the idea that you can distill your entire situation into some tags will not work (the original question). To answer what is in your comment above would depart from this question. Your particular situation is very specific, though not unique really, I think many users in large corporate settings face the same limitations, you can combine a few of your details into single statements/sentences though and some things you will need to use your own best judgment to review answers with.